# Extract all files from dependency

Tags: gradle

I'm trying to build a gradle task which extracts all files in a dependency, so that I can modify them using bytecode enhancement and repackage them to a custom jar.

How can I extract those files to my classes folder?

Comment: What is the goal? If You're trying to prepare executable fat jar there's already plugin for it: https://github.com/musketyr/gradle-fatjar-plugin

Comment: The goal is to modify the existing classes using custom bytecode enhancement. It is not supposed to become an executionable jar, just a modified version of the library :)

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question. So lets split this up,

If you want the dependencies of a project as a File collection, Look at configurations for Gradle. For example, using the java plugin gives you the configurations, configurations.compile and configurations.runtime. [See configurations](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html)

You can loop through collections using a each closure

You can see the contents of an archive using the zipTree method [Example 1](http://java.dzone.com/articles/gradle-goodness-unpacking) [Reference](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/working_with_files.html)

You may also unzip an archive with the ant support within gradle, e.g.

```
ant.unzip(src: war.archivePath, dest: destFile)
```

You can finally build a custom jar using the Jar task type [Jar Task](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.html)